# Quartz UIImage with rounded corners and transparent background on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, quartz-graphics, rounded-corners

I have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14071921/384864) to apply corner radius to `UIImage` in `Quartz`. It works fine like I predicted.

However the corners area outside of the image are not transparent but somewhat colored in white:

[image: UIImage with rounded corners made in Quartz]

The image above shows top left corner of processed image that is opaque and not transparent.

I want cropped-out edges to be totally transparent. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:** If I want to do this with `UIImageView` I would already done this. So please keep in mind that I want to do this with `Quartz` on `UIImage` object not `UIImageView`.

**SOLUTION:** The problem is actually not in the drawing code but rather in writing that image to the file system. I've saved image as JPEG an not as PNG. That's why corners were not transparent cos JPEG does not have alpha filter.

Comment: Edit your question.  Paste in the code that creates the graphics context and draws into it.

Comment: Make sure that the `UIImageView` you are rendering it in has a clear background.

Comment: @robmayoff: The link to the code already exists in code. Here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071278/uiimage-with-smooth-rounded-corners-in-quartz/14071921#14071921

Comment: @msgambel: Clear background on UIImageView does not help if UIImage has no transparent corners...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is actually not in the drawing code but rather in writing that image to the file system. I've saved image as JPEG an not as PNG. That's why corners were not transparent cos JPEG does not have alpha filter.

Just replaced this line of code:

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

... with this one:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a custom category implemented on UIImage to crop the images with round corners. This was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119286/643109) answer.

```
void addRoundedRectToPath(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, float ovalWidth, float ovalHeight, BOOL top, BOOL bottom)
{
    float fw, fh;
    if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        return;
    }
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
    fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
    fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 0);

    NSLog(@"bottom? %d", bottom);

    if (top) {
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 3);
    } else {
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 0);
    }

    if (bottom) {
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 3);
    } else {
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 0);
    }

    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

- (UIImage *)roundCornersOfImage:(UIImage *)source roundTop:(BOOL)top roundBottom:(BOOL)bottom {
    int w = source.size.width;
    int h = source.size.height;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h);
    addRoundedRectToPath(context, rect, 4, 4, top, bottom);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), source.CGImage);

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `transparent` use this:

```
 const float colorMasking[6] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
 yourImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(yourImage.CGImage, colorMasking)];
```

**EDIT** : Add this both line in method of UIImage category

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Could you please refer to this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071278/uiimage-with-smooth-rounded-corners-in-quartz/14071921#14071921

Answer (score 0):

add these bellow lines in your drawRect method ..

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    ///your another code here
}
```

after create Context it required to clear another context from that Rect... so after that line add this line `CGContextClearRect(context, rect);`.

Comment: If you've looked closely at the code this is already done with this line of code: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, 0.0); Second parameter is set to NO which means that opaque is set to NO.

Comment: hey see this answer for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125543/setting-a-cgcontext-transparent-background

Comment: ok ok otherwise may be it is possible that background not clear bcoz some other contenxt are there so.. :) good solution

Comment: yes dude i see the solution after that i post above comment and also +1 for that.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
Image.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
Image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
Image.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
Image.clipsToBounds = YES;
Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Hope it helps you

EDIT :-

I think you just need to add this :-

```
Image.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: UIImage does not have a layer. This is in UIImageView's domain. So not, this is not a solution I want.